# Flutter Admob package stops my app from building

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

After creating a new app in Android Studio which is able to build in iOS and run successfully, I add `admob_flutter: ^0.3.1` as a dependency in pubspec.yaml, get the packages successfully, then rebuild and straight away it fails to build with error:

`Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET admob_flutter OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.`

There's a few threads around the internet that may help with this but they're all about 2 years old so not really sure if they're current and so don't want to mess around and make things worse. Especially since Flutter only came out two years ago anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this issue too. So just create a new Swift file in Runner folder. XCode will redetect your source.

Edit your Pod file as following:

add the `use_frameworks!` like this:

```html
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
```

and

```html
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1' # add this line
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What kind of swift file?

Comment: Right Click on Runner folder on Xcode -> Choose New File -> Choose Swift File -> Done

Comment: Ok I did that and created a new file called 'file.swift' with no bridging header but the error is still there. If I open the pods Xcode project do I need to change the version to 4.2 like it suggests?

Comment: Done all you said but it still fails but has a different error now: `/Users/hasen/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/admob_flutter-0.3.1/ios/Classes/AdmobFlutterPlugin.m:20:9: fatal error: 'admob_flutter/admob_flutter-Swift.h' file not found` The admob flutter package is definitely installed and showing in Dart Packages though.

Comment: Ok I added that line to my pod file but still getting the error in my comment above about the swift.h file not being found...